# Using setp to hide axes spines

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, axes

I am trying to use `setp` in `matplotlib` to set the visibility of spines to `False`, but I get the error "`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'update'`".
As far as I understand, with `setp` we can change the properties of iterable objects, and want to execute it with `spines`.

What is the correct syntax to effectively use `setp`?

Hier a MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(0,10)
y = [i*i for i in x]

plt.plot(x,y) #Plotting x against y
axes = plt.gca() #Getting the current axis

axes.spines['top'].set_visible(False) #It works

plt.setp(axes.spines, visible=False) #It rises error

plt.show() #Showing the plot
```

**Versions:** python3.8.2, Matplotlib 3.2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`axes.spines` is an `OrderedDict`. When you iterate over a `Dict` or `OrderedDict` like this:

```
for key in axes.spines:
    print(type(key))
```

You are iterating over the keys, which are strings and have no update method. [Here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.setp.html) you can see what parameters can be set with `plt.setp()` by just passing in the iterable or object like so.

```
plt.setp(axes.spines)
```

This returns `None`, because its referring to the keys, which are strings and have no update method.
Along this line of logic if we try this:

```
plt.setp(axes.spines.values())
```

we see that this does return possible arguments.
So in summary, changing `plt.setp(axes.spines, visible=False)` to `plt.setp(axes.spines.values(), visible=False)` will remove all spines since it is iterating through the objects and not the keys.

Full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(0,10)
y = [i*i for i in x]

plt.plot(x,y) #Plotting x against y
axes = plt.gca() #Getting the current axis

axes.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

plt.setp(axes.spines.values(), visible=False) 

plt.show() #Showing the plot
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not only for the answer, but for the clear explanations. That is how I imagine answers should be: practical and giving a lot of insight. (By the way, being your name Axe319, you must be an "axes" expert ;))

Answer (score 0):

I will post my desperate solution, only for the record, and if it might help somebody. Though @axe319 answer can hardly be trumped.

I just had to iterate over the names of the spines names:

```
spine_names = ('top','right', 'bottom', 'left')
for spine_name in spine_names:
    axes.spines[spine_name].set_visible(False)
```

It works, but is not so elegant and flexible, and, obviously, gives up on using `setp` :-\

**Warning:**
Somebody might think that an alternative solution is

```
axes.set_frame_on(False)
```

But, not at all. I tried it. Although it certainly hides all axes at once as using `set_visible(False)`, afterwards the command `axes.spines[spine_name].set_visible(True)` does not work!